# When do you use parenthesis in callback functions? ES6 Style

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, callback, functional-programming

```
const billerBuilder = (stateName) => {
  const innerBuilder = (customShipping, customTax) => {
    return (itemPrice) => (itemPrice * customShipping * customTax);
  }
  const nyShipping = 1.03;
  const nyTax = 1.04;
  const njShipping = 1.05;
  const njTax = 1.06625;
  switch (stateName) {
    case 'NY':
      return innerBuilder(nyTax, nyShipping);
    case 'NJ':
      return innerBuilder(njTax, njShipping);
    default:
      return itemPrice;
  }
}
let newYorkBiller = biller('NY');
newYorkBiller(100);
```

why isn't innerBuilder with 3 params the one that gets returned to billerBuilder? Why does the unnamed function with param itemPrice the one that becomes newYorkBiller.

If itemPrice was an unnamed function, how come the code doesn't work when I try to name it?

Comment: How does it not work if you name it?

Comment: "*If itemPrice was an unnamed function*" - which `itemPrice` are you talking about? There are two in your code, one is a parameter of the unnamed arrow function but the second one (that gets returned in the `default` case) is nowhere declared.

Comment: What does the title of your question have to do with the post body? But to answer it: the parenthesis around `stateName`, `itemPrice` and `itemPrice*customShipping*customTax` are indeed unnecessary (not to say superfluous).

Comment: ...customTax) => {
    return (itemPrice)...
i meant the one over here. in ES6 nomenclature, the function with itemPrice as the param is unnamed. But when I try to name it, it throws up flags. I was just wondering if there was a reason why you can't name the function. say...customTax) => funcName = (itemPrice) => like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to name it you should store it in a const and return the const.

```
const innerBuilder = (customShipping, customTax) => {
    const namedFunc = (itemPrice) => (itemPrice * customShipping * customTax);
    return namedFunc;
  }
```

But I don't understand why you would want to name it. If it was me , I would have changed it to:

```
const innerBuilder = (customShipping, customTax) => (itemPrice) => (itemPrice * customShipping * customTax);
```

This technique is called `currying`.

https://medium.com/@kbrainwave/currying-in-javascript-ce6da2d324fe